# Framed box with border inside margin

Tags: framed

I would like to use something like framed, but where the verticals borders are fully within the margins and the position and width of the actual content is unchanged, and with support for nesting the boxes. Is there any environment that supports this? Preferably without explicitly changing attributes for every level of nesting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

[**Edit** I mentioned in my first solution that there is a fancier way to do this, so here it is.]

I am assuming that by "the verticals borders are fully within the margins and the position and width of the actual content is unchanged" you mean that the nested boxes should have the same width as the outer boxes. If this is not the case then you just need to change the values of

```
leftmargin, rightmargin, innerleftmargin, innerrightmargin
```

in the code below. Modulo my awful choice of colours, I think that you are trying to achieve something like the following:

[image]

This was done using the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package and the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{FramedDepth}
\setcounter{FramedDepth}{-1}
\mdfdefinestyle{Framed}{linecolor=black,linewidth=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt,
                        innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt}
\newenvironment{Framed}{%
  \addtocounter{FramedDepth}{1}
  \ifcase\theFramedDepth\def\FrameColour{blue!50}%
    \or\def\FrameColour{green!50}%
    \or\def\FrameColour{red!50}%
    \or\def\FrameColour{orange!50}%
    \fi%
  \begin{mdframed}[style=Framed,backgroundcolor=\FrameColour]%
}{\end{mdframed}\addtocounter{FramedDepth}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Framed}
  Some interesting text.
\end{Framed}

\begin{Framed}
  This is even more interesting.

    \begin{Framed}
      ...and this is beyond mentioning
    \end{Framed}
     Some more text
     \begin{Framed}
       Another level down
     \end{Framed}
  \end{Framed}
\end{Framed}

\end{document}
```

Personally, I prefer to have the nested boxes slightly indented. For example with

```
\mdfdefinestyle{Framed}{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt}
```

you obtain:

[image]